# HTML Navbar menu icon goes down 1 line on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="vc-transp.png" height="50px" style="margin-left: -30px;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><b>Dashboard</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="donate.html">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="protect.html">Protect</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```css
    .nav a{
      color: white !important;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
      color: white !important;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
```

On some screens, the menu icon is in the right place: to the right of the screen, in line with the image.

However, on most smaller screens the menu icon moves down one line and the navbar gets taller. How can I fix this?

Comment: This code works fine, check the parent style. maybe something in parent effects on navbar.

Comment: wdym by parents? - as in <body>?

Comment: Checked this code in bootstrap and it works fine. there are some styles that effect on it. try to debug its not clear here

Comment: possibly `float: right;` in `ul.navbar-nav`?

Comment: I dont know, cause I dont see your codes. try to debug by browser inspect. its not a good question to ask in stack

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for that..
1.Use bootstrap navbar class..that will automatically make your page responsive.
or 
2.Use the css media queries.. you have to define manually for both mobile screen and pc sceeen